# Create object, add pointer to vector, then return it

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, vector

I'm creating a menu class and currently manage controls like so:

```
// .h
class CTab
{
public:
    ...
    CComboBox* AddCombo();

    std::vector<CComboBox*> m_vecControls;
    ...
}

// .cpp
CComboBox* CTab::AddCombo()
{
    auto *combo = new CComboBox();
    m_vecControls.push_back(combo);
    return combo;
}
```

I use a std::vector of pointers to easily iterate all controls when I'm rendering them. I also return the pointer to that object when I initialize the combobox so I can add items to it, for example:

```
auto *comboAge = AddCombo();
comboAge->AddItem("0-15");
comboAge->AddItem("16-30");
comboAge->AddItem("30+");
```

This all works fine, but I'm trying to implement the latest and greatest C++11 features, and I'm not sure which approach to take. Ownership of the controls belongs to the tab, and the ownership of the tab belongs to the window. Would it be best to stop using pointers altogether, and just create a

```
std::vector<CComboBox>
```

? Then I could use

```
m_vecControls.push_back(std::move(combo));
```

but I'm not sure what the best way to return a reference to that would be, so I could add items to it. Another option would be to use smart pointers, then I wouldn't have to delete the objects manually in CTab::~CTab(). So my questions are:

1. Would it be best to stop using pointers, in favor of std::move? If so, how should I return a reference to the created object in AddCombo()?
2. Or would it best to use smart pointers instead of raw pointers? If so, which type? I assume it would have to be shared because I'm keeping a vector of them, in addition to returning the pointer in AddCombo().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `vector< unique_ptr<CComboBox> >` is a simple change you can make that will remove the need for you to remember to `delete` things.  This is for items with single ownership. If you need shared ownership then use `shared_ptr.`

If you go with the `vector<CComboBox>` option you will need to make sure that `CComboBox` supports copy or move semantics correctly. Also think about whether any other part of the code would be storing a pointer to the combo box. If you ever need two different references to the same CComboBox to exist then this probably isn't the best approach.